# eloquent querybuilder pass column to nested query

Tags: database, eloquent

I would like to query the db to retrieve all events that do not have a comment created after the start date. Following structure for EVENT and COMMENT

```
EVENT 
id 
start 
created_at 
updated_at

COMMENT
id
comment
event_id
created_at
updated_at
```

Create a query ( $query = Event::query()->with('comments'); ) which gives me the following construct.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "start": "2018-06-18 12:00:00",
    "created_at": "2018-06-18 11:50:07",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-02 12:13:15",
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2018-06-18 12:44:35",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-18 12:44:35",
            "comment": "cascsac"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to retrieve all entries where comment.created_at is after the start date of the event. I tried with the following:

```
   $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
      $value = $query->where(function ($query) use ('start') {
        $query->whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ('start') {
          $query->where('created_at','<=','start');
          //->whereColumn('created_at', '<=', 'start');
        });
      });
    });
```

But its does not like my attempts to pass start to a nested query and am not sure how to pass it for whereColumn query.

How do I pass values from columns to a nested where.
Or how else do I query a with the value of a separate column.

**Edit1**

On request the whole query

$query

```
Event::query()->with('comments');
$query->orWhere(function ($query) {
          $value = $query->where(function ($query) use ('start') {
            $query->whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ('start') {
              $query->where('created_at','>=','start');
              //->whereColumn('created_at', '>=', 'start');
            });
          });
        });
$events = $query->get();
```

Passing variable $start would work too but I cannot convert column value of start to variable $start to pass the nested query

Comment: Please post the whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/querybuilder-pass-column-to-nested-query

```
$events = Event::with('comments')->whereHas('comments',function ($query) {
   $query->whereColumn('comments.created_at','<','events.start');
})->get();
```

whereColumn is function to compare columns in query.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong code is 'start'> It must be $start

```
 $start = Carbon::now()->subYears(100); // for examplee
 $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
     $value = $query->where(function ($query) use ($start) {
         $query->whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ($start) {
              $query->where('created_at','<=', $start);
              //->whereColumn('created_at', '<=', $start);
         });
     });
 })
```

Comment: how do I convert the value of column start to a variable $start